# Starting with OpenGL - a couple of questions

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to start coding in OpenGL and C++ and I have a couple of questions:

**1.** Should I use OpenGL 4.2 or rather 3.x instead? OpenGL 4.x runs on Nvidia GTX 400+. Does that mean that it is widely supported or should I go for 3.x?

**2.** I found some headers and libraries in Windows SDK, but not all of them. Is there any place where I can find *all* libraries and headers for OpenGL? What I want to avoid is downloading old and different versions from all over the internet.

**3.** Does OpenGL cover input or is this part of the GDI+/WinAPI?

Comment: I'm sorry, must have 'misspelled' it. I'm gonna correct it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should go for what you want to support. The major OpenGL version (3,4) is typically used for identifying hardware generations, while the minor versions are really targeted at functional releases, which should be independent of your hardware. For example: I have now 4.2 features while that didn't even exist when I bought this GPU. So you can count that up-to-date drivers will support the latest minor version. But no matter how you try, your GPU won't get new hw functions with a driver update. Note that a tricky part is that not all GPU's are still supported. This means driver updates are no longer provisioned and they could be stuck at some minor OpenGL version.
2. There are wrappers that do most things for you, but do not forget that you still need to link to the `gl` and possibly `glu` libraries and some platform-specific ones. I personally like the [unofficial OpenGL SDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html), glload is the library that you want. The other libraries are also quite useful.
3. OpenGL does not cover input, it is just for drawing. Also note that OpenGL does not create the default framebuffer for you. The default framebuffer is the thing you render to (usually in a window). This is done by platform specific functions, for windows this is [WGL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I used SDL for that several months ago. I even implemented stencil shadows but some basic things were missing. Also I want to use the plain/original includes and libraries like GL.lib, GL.h, glu.h, glut.h etc.
So maybe I should use OpenGL 3.x. Could you point me to a good collection of up to date headers/libs with everything from gl to glut?

Comment: if you want to support older hardwares, i recommend using opengl 2.1 which i currently use. you can use glsl, the shading language for it easily and you can establish really good graphics for your game. if you ask me, supporting older hardwares is the most important thing.

Comment: @DevilsChild: the headers for use in your program are provided by `glload`. The OpenGL headers and libraries (which it uses) install is platform dependent, so no I can't help with that. But take a look at the [getting started guide](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started) on opengl.org

Comment: As for the platform, I'm looking for Windows only headers & libraries. Also I have a bad feeling about using glload. I'd rather stick to something official. There must be some kind of initial source for all libraries and headers, isn't there?

Comment: @DevilsChild: glload is just a "wrapper" that loads a lot of opengl extensions for you (which you really need on windows). You can do this manually, but then you're in for a world of pain and maintenance hell. glload and alternatives like glew have been tried and tested, it's not just a library I tend to like, a lot of people actually use it.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a closer look at this. Thanks :)

Comment: [glsdk build](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html) says "At present, the OpenGL SDK has not been tested under any form of Mac OS". Can anyone comment please ?